# Scrapy ~ raise NotImplementedError

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I keep getting the following error when trying to run my scrapy script..

Error::

```
    2017-06-08 07:32:02 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://xxxx.orderxxxx.com/PartLookup.aspx?company=001&language=en-us> (referer: None)
```

Below is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import *
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import json
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ['xxxx.orderxxxx.com']
    start_urls = ['https://xxxx.orderxxxx.com/vehiclePartLookupByZip.aspx?company=001&language=en-us']

def parse(self, response):
    form_data = {
        'VarsSessionID': '',
        '__VIEWSTATE':     '/wEPDwULLTE3NDkxNjc2NjIPZBYCAgEPZBYCAgcPZBYCZg9kFgYCCQ8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCDQ8PFgIfAGhkZAIfD2QWCAIJDxBkEBVcES0gU2VsZWN0IGEgWWVhciAtBDIwMTgEMjAxNwQyMDE2BDIwMTUEMjAxNAQyMDEzBDIwMTIEMjAxMQQyMDEwBDIwMDkEMjAwOAQyMDA3BDIwMDYEMjAwNQQyMDA0BDIwMDMEMjAwMgQyMDAxBDIwMDAEMTk5OQQxOTk4BDE5OTcEMTk5NgQxOTk1BDE5OTQEMTk5MwQxOTkyBDE5OTEEMTk5MAQxOTg5BDE5ODgEMTk4NwQxOTg2BDE5ODUEMTk4NAQxOTgzBDE5ODIEMTk4MQQxOTgwBDE5NzkEMTk3OAQxOTc3BDE5NzYEMTk3NQQxOTc0BDE5NzMEMTk3MgQxOTcxBDE5NzAEMTk2OQQxOTY4BDE5NjcEMTk2NgQxOTY1BDE5NjQEMTk2MwQxOTYyBDE5NjEEMTk2MAQxOTU5BDE5NTgEMTk1NwQxOTU2BDE5NTUEMTk1NAQxOTUzBDE5NTIEMTk1MQQxOTUwBDE5NDkEMTk0OAQxOTQ3BDE5NDYEMTk0NQQxOTQ0BDE5NDMEMTk0MgQxOTQxBDE5NDAEMTkzOQQxOTM4BDE5MzcEMTkzNgQxOTM1BDE5MzQEMTkzMwQxOTMyBDE5MzEEMTkzMAQxOTI5BDE5MjgVXBEtIFNlbGVjdCBhIFllYXIgLQQyMDE4BDIwMTcEMjAxNgQyMDE1BDIwMTQEMjAxMwQyMDEyBDIwMTEEMjAxMAQyMDA5BDIwMDgEMjAwNwQyMDA2BDIwMDUEMjAwNAQyMDAzBDIwMDIEMjAwMQQyMDAwBDE5OTkEMTk5OAQxOTk3BDE5OTYEMTk5NQQxOTk0BDE5OTMEMTk5MgQxOTkxBDE5OTAEMTk4OQQxOTg4BDE5ODcEMTk4NgQxOTg1BDE5ODQEMTk4MwQxOTgyBDE5ODEEMTk4MAQxOTc5BDE5NzgEMTk3NwQxOTc2BDE5NzUEMTk3NAQxOTczBDE5NzIEMTk3MQQxOTcwBDE5NjkEMTk2OAQxOTY3BDE5NjYEMTk2NQQxOTY0BDE5NjMEMTk2MgQxOTYxBDE5NjAEMTk1OQQxOTU4BDE5NTcEMTk1NgQxOTU1BDE5NTQEMTk1MwQxOTUyBDE5NTEEMTk1MAQxOTQ5BDE5NDgEMTk0NwQxOTQ2BDE5NDUEMTk0NAQxOTQzBDE5NDIEMTk0MQQxOTQwBDE5MzkEMTkzOAQxOTM3BDE5MzYEMTkzNQQxOTM0BDE5MzMEMTkzMgQxOTMxBDE5MzAEMTkyOQQxOTI4FCsDXGdnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnFgFmZAINDxBkEBUBES0gU2VsZWN0IGEgTWFrZSAtFQERLSBTZWxlY3QgYSBNYWtlIC0UKwMBZxYBZmQCEQ8QZBAVARItIFNlbGVjdCBhIE1vZGVsIC0VARItIFNlbGVjdCBhIE1vZGVsIC0UKwMBZxYBZmQCFQ8QZBAVARUtIFNlbGVjdCBhIENhdGVnb3J5IC0VARUtIFNlbGVjdCBhIENhdGVnb3J5IC0UKwMBZxYBZmRkW3snnFJQXlxa5cFaGgo4Mh5Tbr6vJZWrCYmbroXUnEs='}
yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                formid='frmChangePage',
                                formdata=form_data,
                                method='POST',
                                callback=self.after_parse,
                                url='https://xxxx.orderxxxx.com/vehiclePartLookupByZip.aspx?company=001&language=en-us',
                                )

def after_parse(self, response):
    print "====RESPONSE==="
    print response.headers
    print "=========="
    print response.request.headers
    print "=========="
    VarsSessionID = Selector(response=response).xpath("//*    [@id='VarsSessionID']/@value").extract()[0]
    viewstate = Selector(response=response).xpath("//*[@id='__VIEWSTATE']/@value").extract()[0]
    print "VarsSessionID: " + VarsSessionID
    print "__VIEWSTATE: " + viewstate
    url = "https://xxxx.orderxxxx.com/B2BAjaxCalls.asmx/js"
    payload = {
        "FormData":
            {
        'txtZipCode': '85015',
        'cboYears': ['2004'],
        'cboMake': ['HONDA'],
        'cboModel': ['CIVIC_COUPE'],
        'cboCategory': ['AXLE SHAFT']
            }, 
    }
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en_US',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': {'VarsSessionID':''},
        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
}
yield Request(url,
              callback=self.after_search,
              method='POST',
              body=json.dumps(payload),
              headers=headers)

def after_search(self, response):
    print "========SEARCH HEADERS========"
    print response.headers
    print response.request.headers
    open_in_browser(response)
```

Scrapy keeps throwing an error..

```
2017-06-08 07:32:02 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://xxxx.orderxxxx.com/vehiclePart.aspx?company=001&language=en-us> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 90, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

I was wondering if someone can take a look and point me in the right direction to resolve this error.

Comment: Your code is badly formatted, `parse` should be indented under your spider class.

Comment: Thanks.. That worked!!